# $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the continuity of $f_i : ( x_1 , \ldots , x_n ) \mapsto x_i^h$ for $h \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $h \geq 1$ be an integer; let $f_{i}: (x_{1},\dots x_{n}) \mapsto (x_{i})^h: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Show that each $f_{i}$ is continuous. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, must come up with a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x-a| <  \delta$.

I'm stuck with coming up with such a $\delta$ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h \in \mathbb{N}$; without loss of generality, suppose $f: (x_{1},\dots, x_{n}) \to x_{n}^{h}$. If $(c_{1}, \dots, c_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $(x_{1},\dots, x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ only if 
$$
| f(x_{1},\dots, x_{n}) - f(c_{1},\dots, c_{n})| = |x_{n}^{h} - c_{n}^{h}| \leq |x_{n} - c_{n}| \sum_{k=0}^{h-1}|x_{n}^{k}c_{n}^{h-1-k}|;
$$
if $|x_{n} - c_{n}| < 1$, then $|x_{n}| < 1 + |c_{n}|$ by "triangle inequality", and hence 
$$
|x_{n} - c_{n}|\sum_{k=0}^{h-1}|x_{n}^{k}c_{n}^{h-1-k}| < |x_{n}-c_{n}|\sum_{k=0}^{h-1}| 1 + |c_{n}||^{k}|c_{n}|^{h-1-k} =: |x_{n}-c_{n}|M;
$$
if $\varepsilon > 0$, then $|x_{n}-c_{n}| < \varepsilon/M$ only if $|x_{n} - c_{n}|M < \varepsilon$; 
hence we have proved this: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|x_{n} - c_{n}| < \min \{1, \varepsilon/M \}$ only if $|f(x_{1},\dots, x_{n}) - f(c_{1},\dots, c_{n})| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Is the δ = min{1,M}, where M = $\sum_{k=0}^{h-1} |1+|c_n||^k|c_n|^{h-1-k}$  in this case? If $|x_n - c_n|$ < ε/M here, wouldn't δ be min{1, ε/M} ? Also, the proof might be the opposite direction, since I want to prove if $|x-a|$ < δ then $|f(x)-f(a)|$ < ε

Comment: Don't be panic; it is just a typo... :) I have shown you that $|x_{n} - c_{n}| < \min \{1, \varepsilon/M \}$ implies $|f(x_{1},\dots, x_{n}) - f(c_{1},\dots, c_{n})| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: By the way, "only if" means "to imply". :)